# Hiw can I show the a msg from an ajax call from a dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, jquery-ui

I make an AJAX call to a server and retrieve occasionally a warning msg I need to show to the user.
I tried `alert` and it works but it looks bad as the text is long and unformatted.
Googling I found that JQuery has a [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) widget that suits me but I can not figure out how
to pass the content string to display. I see that I can pass a text to be the dialog's title but if in ajax call
I have a `var result_msg` how can I open the dialog to show in the main body the text of `result_msg`?

Comment: `$('#dialog').html(result_msg);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in your success function of ajax:

```
$( "#dialog-message" ).html(respTxt).dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Ok: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    }
}).css('height', 200);// <-----------------------add this and below one
$('.ui-widget-overlay').css('height', 'auto');
```

[Fiddle for help.](http://jsfiddle.net/AujAL/)
[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AujAL/1/)

Comment: +1. It works. Only issue I have is that I do a `window.location.reload(true);` right after the construction/display of the dialog and this has as result to show the dialog for only a brief second.If I don't reload then it stays. How can I make it so that I am able to show the dialog and on press ok the line `window.location.reload(true);` is executed?

Comment: `window.location.reload(true);` you can put this in `OK` function.

Comment: One last thing. It displays the text already scrolled down. I mean it is a long text and instead of seeing
the top and scrolling down I see the bottom and I scroll up

Comment: It works!Thank you very much.BTW what is the need of `$('.ui-widget-overlay').css('height', 'auto');`?

Comment: actually it was pushing the browser to scroll down but you can omit it if that works.